# .net core warmup cache IIS preload handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, .net-core, application-pool

In my Startup class and the Configure method of my .net core application I am initializing some cached lists through MemoryCache. I have been trying to use IIS autostart feature (https://www.simple-talk.com/blogs/speeding-up-your-application-with-the-iis-auto-start-feature/)

I am having problems to get this to work with .net core though. I realized that I can get the specified method running by creating a bin-folder in the root-catalog.

I can see in event-log that the following code gets excecuted:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
var client = new WebDownload();
sw.Start();
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(url));
client.DownloadStringCompleted += (sender, e) =>
{
    sw.Stop();
    using (EventLog eventLog = new EventLog("Application"))
    {
        eventLog.Source = "Application";
        eventLog.WriteEntry("client.DownloadString(url) - färdigkörd (" + sw.ElapsedMilliseconds + " ms, " + e.Result + ")", EventLogEntryType.Information, 101, 1);
    }
};
```

But I still get a first-time delay after this has been triggered. Any suggestions how to solve this or what am I doing wrong? Something makes the iis crashing that might be the reason why this isnt working. In windows event log i can see that w3wp.exe is crashing a short time after above code was triggered. Are there any better ways to handle this in a .net core app running under iis?

Comment: There's also a first-time delay compiling razor views which can take some time on the first view. Are you sure it is not this delay? (e.g. when you run the same init code in a "hello world" app without MVC)

Comment: Try to define the `var client = new WebDownload();`    at the class level.

Comment: Allright, so probably one of the delays is the compiling of razor view. But in this case it seems like my "preload" code is triggered but then w3wp.exe crashes and when visiting page it seems like the initial load, which takes some time, like 20 seconds or so. Seems like a hacky solution overall putting file under bin folder and to call my webpage from code, can I solve this in a more neat way with .net core..?